# не могу составить комбинацию чисел от 0 до 20 в вариативном порядке по 40 штук комбинаций в пайтон

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from itertools import combinations

# Генерируем все комбинации чисел от 0 до 20 размером 40 штук
combs = list(combinations(range(21), 40))

print("Количество комбинаций:", len(combs))

# Выводим первые 5 комбинаций
for i in range(5):
    print(combs[i])
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и [*минимальный код*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: я не могу решить. у меня возникает проблема . вместо этого вижу ответ в виде print("???????????????", len(combs))

Comment: что я делаю не так?

Comment: если вам не интересно, то и необязательно дизлайкать, этим вы никому не угодите, и при этом ценности в этом нет ни малейшей.

Comment: 'дизлайк" (голос против) означает не то, что мне не интересно, а то, что я считаю этот вопрос низкокачественным.

Comment: какой вопрос? я лишь хочу понять какие у меня ошибки в скрипте  и только. тем более , я еще только начинающий. не думаю что специалистам так сложно в этом мне помочь

Comment: Если ты не удосужился прочитать [ask], то не нужно обижаться на минусы. Обижайся на себя самого.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В документации сказано: 0 <= r <= n, где r - второе передаваемое функции значение, обозначающее то, сколько чисел будет в группе, а n - длина итерируемого массива (`range(n)`). Вы передаете n = 21, а r = 40. Чуете в чем подвох? Если вам необходимо получить первые 40 комбинаций из двух чисел, то следует использовать `combs = list(combinations(range(21), 2))[:40]`.
Исправленная версия кода:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from itertools import combinations

r = int(input("Введите количество чисел в одной группе: "))
# Генерируем все комбинации чисел от 0 до 20 размером 40 штук
combs = list(combinations(range(21), r))[:40]

print("Количество комбинаций:", len(combs))

# Выводим первые 5 комбинаций
for i in range(5):
    print(combs[i])
```